# How to recover AWS SNS subject and message from CloudWatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a SNS topic and a HTTP subscription to it, the HTTP post method I created it does some stuff in eveery received message notification, everything works fine... the thing is that when I try to retrieve information about the message from CloudWatch logs I am unable to get the subject and message sent to the client... here it is an example:

This is the JSON received from AWS in my HTTP method:

```
{
   "Type":"Notification",
   "MessageId":"9d1a1104-d1bf-51b9-8289-49382a1a603e",
   "TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:554218924367:Airbus_SNS_Topic",
   "Subject":"Test Subject",
   "Message":"Test body message",
   "Timestamp":"2020-11-29T01:29:09.159Z",
   "SignatureVersion":"1"
 }
```

When I go to Cloudwatch logs the information I got is like this:

```
{
   "notification":{
      "messageMD5Sum":"bb5553b8c3c1c9386ce8c8c8fef10874",
      "messageId":"9d1a1104-d1bf-51b9-8289-49382a1a603e",
      "topicArn":"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:554218924367:Airbus_SNS_Topic",
      "timestamp":"2020-11-29 01:29:09.166"
   },
   "delivery":{
      "deliveryId":"fb688918-aec3-54b7-b941-d124556667a9",
      "destination":"www.mydomain.com/myhttppostmethod",
      "providerResponse":"OK",
      "dwellTimeMs":9416,
      "attempts":1,
      "statusCode":200
   },
   "status":"SUCCESS"
}
```

The "important" information is not displayed in the logs, I mean the message subject and body are not logged, In this case "Test subject" and "Test body message" is this because a privacy policy configuration or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That is by design**. SNS delivery status logging only records if a message of given ID was delivered or not. It does not log its body.

You can read more about SNS deliver status logging [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-the-delivery-status-feature-of-amazon-sns/) or [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html).

If you want to log the body, you can subscribe a lambda function to your topic which will write full messages to CloudWatch Logs or DynamoDB for example.